# Extract the time from a UUID v1 in python

Tags: python, timestamp, uuid

I have some UUIDs that are being generated in my program at random, but I want to be able to extract the timestamp of the generated UUID for testing purposes. I noticed that using the `fields` accessor I can get the various parts of the timestamp but I have no idea on how to combine them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looking inside /usr/lib/python2.6/uuid.py you'll see

```
def uuid1(node=None, clock_seq=None):
    ...
    nanoseconds = int(time.time() * 1e9)
    # 0x01b21dd213814000 is the number of 100-ns intervals between the
    # UUID epoch 1582-10-15 00:00:00 and the Unix epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
    timestamp = int(nanoseconds/100) + 0x01b21dd213814000L
```

solving the equations for time.time(), you'll get

```
time.time()-like quantity = ((timestamp - 0x01b21dd213814000L)*100/1e9)
```

So use:

```
In [3]: import uuid

In [4]: u = uuid.uuid1()

In [58]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((u.time - 0x01b21dd213814000L)*100/1e9)
Out[58]: datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 25, 17, 43, 6, 298623)
```

This gives the datetime associated with a UUID generated by `uuid.uuid1`.

Comment: Looks like you solved my problem. In the meantime I had to go back and create my own constructor since it was generating only the current timestamps, and I needed random past timestamps. Thanks for your quick answer :-)

Comment: interesting, uuid epoch refers to the Julian calendar.. (facepalm)

Comment: @ezdazuzena Actually, Gregorian (see [RFC 4122, section 4.1.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.4) about Gregorian reform to the Christian calendar). This is totally arbitrary, of course, but so is the UNIX epoch. I challenge you to pick a better one, explain why your decision is not just as arbitrary, *and* demonstrate a need to change the existing standard (and the slew of dependent and indirectly dependent ones) to follow yours instead.

Answer (score 19):

You could use a simple formula that follows directly [from the definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.4):

> The timestamp is a 60-bit value.  For UUID version 1, this is
> represented by Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) as a count of 100-
> nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00, 15 October 1582 (the date of
> Gregorian reform to the Christian calendar).

```
>>> from uuid import uuid1
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime(1582, 10, 15) + timedelta(microseconds=uuid1().time//10)
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 13, 6, 59, 12, 109560)
```

Answer (score 12):

Or just use the [TimeUUID library](https://pythonhosted.org/time-uuid), so that you know you didn't get the math wrong

Example

```
import uuid
import time_uuid

my_uuid = uuid.UUID('{12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678}')
ts = time_uuid.TimeUUID(bytes=my_uuid.bytes).get_timestamp()
```

Comment: I tried calling `print(time_uuid.TimeUUID(bytes=uuid.uuid1().bytes).get_datetime())` constantly but I saw the time only changes every 2 secs. It doesn't seem to calculate precisely.

Comment: But I see that uuid1().time has different values each time it is called, which is what I expected. Given that I only wanted to know which one was created first, comparing them by `uuid1().time` did the trick for me.

Comment: I would not recommend adding a dependency for what amounts to one line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Since I have Cassandra installed and I am using this with Cassandra I was able to use the datetime_from_uuid1 from cassandra.util

```
>>> import uuid
>>> from cassandra.util import datetime_from_uuid1
>>> foo = uuid.uuid1()
>>> dt_foo = datetime_from_uuid1(foo)
>>> dt_foo
datetime.datetime(2016, 07, 26, 8, 2, 12, 104560)
```