# Extract time from a UUID v1 in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, uuid

I have stored data that has a UUID v1 as key and I now want to know when the UUID was generated. How do I do that the nice way?

Comment: Here is how it is done in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795554/extract-the-time-from-a-uuid-v1-in-python maybe use it as a template.

Comment: I found [this little recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576420-get-a-posix-timestamp-from-a-type-1-uuid/) in Python. Since I'm not good at Ruby, could someone make this for Ruby please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with irb:

```
require 'simple_uuid'
uuid = SimpleUUID::UUID.new
uuid.to_guid # actually this is what I have stored in my database
Time.at(SimpleUUID::UUID.new(uuid.to_guid).seconds) # returns the time and date of the UUID
```

Thanks to my friend KillerFox, he showed me the simple solution.