# Where do UUID namespaces come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, uuid, standards

The [UUID specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.3) defines 4 predefined namespaces which it describes as "potentially interesting" - meaning among other things, "if other people have generated UUIDs in this namespace you can verify them":

- `6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8` for DNS
- `6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8` for URL
- `6ba7b812-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8` for ISO OID
- `6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8` for X.500 DN

Where did these come from?

Specifically;

- If I'm generating my own namespace UUID do I need to avoid anything in particular?
- I'm aware how big the UUID space is, but does this have any implication on collisions?
- Why have they chosen the 4th octet to increase as a kind of UUID 'version number'?
- Do my questions imply that I'm missing something fundamental about UUIDs?

Comment: The rfc4122 says: "The
   mechanisms or conventions used for allocating names and ensuring
   their uniqueness within their name spaces are beyond the scope of
   this specification." in 4.3 ^^ But I don't know where it is specified.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First, to be clear, this whole discussion is limited to version 3 & 5 UUIDs.  In my (anecdotal) experience, version 4 (random) UUIDs are most commonly used.

[4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.3)'s namespaced UUID generation algorithm ambiguously begins:

> Allocate a UUID to use as a "name space ID"

There is no other mention of "name space ID" allocation, and neither I nor [python](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) have found any standardized spaces beyond the four listed in RFC 4122.

So the answer to your first question,

> - If I'm generating my own namespace UUID do I need to avoid anything in particular?

You only need to avoid the four standard namespaces.

---

The next question,

> - I'm aware how big the UUID space is, but does this have any implication on collisions?

Has two parts:

1. Will UUIDs within your namespace collide?  Verbatim from 4122:

   > The UUIDs generated from two different names in [your] namespace should be different (with very high probability).
2. Will your namespace UUID collide with other namespaces?  I couldn't find a direct answer, since there's no standard for "name space ID" allocation, but the argument in [section 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.1.3) seems relevant:

   > Interoperability, in any form, with variants other than the one
   > defined here is not guaranteed, and is not likely to be an issue in
   > practice.

---

> - Why have they chosen the 4th octet to increase as a kind of UUID 'version number'?

This one's a bit of a mystery.  Luckily, we have a spec for UUIDs, so we can mine them for some insight.

Note that the (0-index) 8th octet starts with `8` in all cases, so we're dealing with **RFC 4122 variant** UUIDs.  Phew.

Now check octet 6 for the version: `1`, we're dealing with **version 1 time-based** UUIDs.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795554/extract-the-time-from-a-uuid-v1-in-python) has a handy algorithm for extracting python datetimes from version 1 UUIDs.  Applying the algorithm yields a time in **February 4th, 1998**.  I have yet to find meaning in this date.  Incrementing the 3rd octet adds the smallest encodable time interval (100ns) to the date.

---

> - Do my questions imply that I'm missing something fundamental about UUIDs?

Nope.  There is very little discussion of UUID namespaces, since random UUIDs are so easy.

Comment: That's great, especially the deconstruction of those namespaces. It seems like February 4th, 1998 corresponds with the date of the UUID draft specification - http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01

Comment: The namespace UUIDs are version 1. I believe you calculated the date correctly. The final 12 hex characters are the Host ID, and usually calculated from the MAC address of the machine generating the UUID. Using on-line OUI databases, we can tell that "00c04f" mean's it was generated on a Dell box. Personally, I want to know what happened to "6ba7b813"... :)

Comment: @ChrisCogdon re: `what happened to "6ba7b813"` - perhaps the spec writers were triskaidekaphobic, or feared we were. :)

Answer (score 4):

> If I'm generating my own namespace UUID do I need to avoid anything in particular?

No.  Your namespace UUID can be any UUID generated in any of the normal ways.  So, for example, you would probably want to generate a version 1 or version 4 UUID to use as your namespace UUID.  This can be done with the `uuidgen` program on Linux or OS X.  Or you can easily generate a [version 1](http://cloanto.com/uuid/?quantity=1&action=Generate) or [version 4](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uuid&ia=answer) UUID online.

Comment: Alternatively, use one of the standard namespace UUIDs (Appendix C of RFC 4122) and the string of your namespace to generate `your` root namespace UUID.  Then use that and the names within that namespace to generate each needed UUID.  E.g., something like: `root = uuid(uuid.URL, "www.example.com"); page1 = uuid(root, "page1.html"); page2 = uuid(root, "page2.html");` // yes, I'm assuming the ctor of uuid knows what to do. :)