# How can I calculate a UUID of a person?

Tags: uuid

I'd like to calculate a UUID by using some basic personal data:

- Given name(s) at time of birth
- Surname(s) at time of birth
- Birth date
- Birth place

It's absolutely necessary that the person's UUID won't change later in the person's life. This is why I'll take the person's name *at time of birth*, exactly as stated in his/her birth certificate (including the writing system used), if such document exists (which is not always the case in poor countries, unfortunately). The character set will be UTF-8.

Now there are already name-based UUIDs (with version 5 being the current one), but calculating it requires me to use a *namespace UUID*. There are such namespace UUIDs for URLs, hostnames, and other entities, but apparently not personal names. So: If I can get such a namespace UUID, it won't be problematic to hash the personal data and to combine them into a ready-to-use UUID. But: How can I get or calculate the necessary namespace UUID?

** UPDATE: ** I received the hint that [Where do UUID namespaces come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724903/where-do-uuid-namespaces-come-from) might contain the answer to my quiestion. Although the answers stated there so help me much in understanding the namespace UUID phenomenon, I've still got one issue: How do I generate a namespace UUID the folks in the outside world will accept? Shall I register such a namespace with the IANA, as I'd do it with an ISO
OID?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: You can't, because those things are not guaranteed universally unique, not even all taken together. Use a real uuid instead, which is guaranteed unique exactly because it's _not_ based on your data, and then save it into that person's record.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do UUID namespaces come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724903/where-do-uuid-namespaces-come-from)

Comment: @TomTom I don't see what's so wrong with this idea. There are many use cases where you want a reproducible hash and not a random number.

Comment: @Progman Why would that matter? The question is about the UUIDv5 format, which is language-agnostic.

Comment: @Progman: If possible, I'll need a language-agnostic solution I can implement in Java, C++, C#, or whatever language.

Comment: "I don't see what's so wrong with this idea." Over engineered, no security or any other benefit, not unique by definition outside a controlled population and generally "nice, you are fired, with cause" level unless you have a RASON, not a "I do not understand what is wrong" because then I want you to not understand that working for the competition. You do not do complex without a benefit and you do not have one at all.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The issue is: When I start to generate a UUID for a particular person, he/she will give me his/her (digital?) birth certificate, and when I calculate a UUID from these personal data, I must always get the same UUID. Reason: Such data are not always stored in centralised systems (think of a refugee camp in a dirt-poor country), and documents can get lost.

Comment: You could just hash whatever information you have. Maybe normalize before hashing. But I'm not cure I understand the use case. Which dirt poor country has digital birth certificates? As name + birthplace won't be unique, neither will be your uuids or hashes.

Comment: @Neppomuk birth data is not stable data. I've run into plenty of cases where birth dates (especially migrant birth dates) have to get adjusted, because the real world is messy: you can't rely on the assumption that any of the things you've listed will stay the same throughout the lifetime of a person (and something like "name at time of birth" almost  universally isn't a thing, names are generally registered some period _after_ birth, existing in government registries that are technically independently of birth data).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for the warning. I'm gonna address these issues before introducing such UUIDs on a wide scale. Even if there is no birth certificate available, I can still compute the UUID based on the data the person in question (or the parents, if the person is a kid), but make sure that when the person is registered, the same name and bitrh data will be used.

Comment: You might be using the wrong term though: it sounds like what you really want is some kind of (possibly hashed) compound key, and definitely not a uuid, as the term "uuid" refers to a very specific kind of thing: "universally unique identifiers" are _by definition_ not based on your data, but on some universal property (e.g. based on time, hardware uuids, unique namespaces, etc) relevant only to sequence generation, that ensures you get a unique (the pigeon hole principle notwithstanding) sequence of identifiers no matter how many, and no matter how fast you generate identifiers.

Comment: Why the down-vote? The author has certainly misunderstood the nature and purpose of UUIDs, but such a misunderstanding and abuse of UUIDs is not uncommon. The Question is clear, thoughtful, and researched — though misguided. Misguided questions *are* allowed here, where an Answer can hopefully enlighten the OP and the reader.

Comment: By the way, the same visible character can be encoded in different ways in Unicode (e.g. é vs e and combing-accent separately)

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to calculate a UUID by using some basic personal data

A UUID is not meant to store data values. A UUID is meant to create a virtually unique identifier without coordinating through a centralized server.

> necessary that the person's UUID won't change later in the person's life

All of those personal details can change because of clerical errors that are corrected later. And some religious/cultural practices complete the person’s name some time *after* birth, at an arranged ceremony.

Also, many governments have an agency that dispense life-long identifiers to their citizens. So your goal seems a strange one.

> The character set will be UTF-8.

UUIDs have no characters.

UUIDs have only bits, 128 of them. A few of those bits have specific meaning (semantics), indicating the version and variant of UUID type.

> I'd like to calculate a UUID

Whatever value you are trying to invent, stop calling it a UUID. A [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is a very specific, narrowly-defined data structure. A specification, [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122), spells out this structure precisely in a written standard. If you do not wish to abide by that specification, fine, that is your prerogative. But don’t call your invention a “UUID”.

You have misunderstood the purpose of a UUID. A UUID is meant to be used in situations where you cannot rely upon the data values given by your problem domain. If you *can* rely upon the given data, make a [natural key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) of them, a [composite key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key) if you want to combine them for uniqueness. UUIDs on the other hand are suitable for use as a [surrogate key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

> name-based UUIDs (with version 5

Those versions of UUID are meant to use the name across a swath of UUID values, not varying per each UUID value.

Comment: I meant the characters of the person's name, which will be UTF-8-encoded. And I've never intended to store data in a UUID, just to use it as a primary key without having to rely on central IT infrastructure.

Comment: @Neppomuk If you are not trying to store data within the UUID, why not just use Version 1 or 4 UUID and be done with it? Why ask your Question here, asking to combine birth data? If you truly want "a primary key without having to rely on central IT infrastructure", then Version 1 or 4 UUID meets that need handily. Involving birth data adds no value, especially since any of that data may not yet be known, and may change.

Comment: By the way, there is an effort underway to standardize [Version 6, 7, & 8](https://uuid6.github.io/uuid6-ietf-draft/) UUIDs. The main goal is facilitating storage in databases & indexes.