# Using Python's UUID to generate unique IDs, should I still check for duplicates?

Tags: python, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I'm using Python's UUID function to create unique IDs for objects to be stored in a database:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> print uuid.uuid4()
2eec67d5-450a-48d4-a92f-e387530b1b8b
```

Is it ok to assume that this is indeed a unique ID?

Or should I double-check that this unique ID has not already been generated against my database before accepting it as valid.

Comment: [This question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130261/uuid-collisions) may be informative.  In essence, it is possible that the ID is nonunique, however the chance of that is unbelievably small.

Comment: The odds of two `uuid4`s colliding are 1 in `16**32`.

Comment: @roippi It's not that easy. Part of the UUID is a timestamp. So, if the UUIDs were generated at different times, the probability of a duplicate is 0. Otherwise, it depends on the RNG that's being used. [In Python 3](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Lib/uuid.py), the RNG of libc or libuuid is used, if available. Otherwise, it tries `os.urandom` and falls back to the `random` module. So, in conclusion, you should be safe. (Sorry for being overly specific, but I thought that might be interesting, for you or for the OP or someone else.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use `uuid1`, which has zero chance of collisions since it takes date/time into account when generating the UUID (unless you are generating a great number of UUID's at the same time).

You can actually [reverse the UUID1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795750/276949) value to retrieve the original epoch time that was used to generate it.

`uuid4` generates a random ID that has a very small chance of colliding with a previously generated value, however since it doesn't use monotonically increasing epoch time as an input (or include it in the output uuid), a value that was previously generated has a (very) small chance of being generated again in the future.

Comment: uuid version 1 are guaranteed.unique only if you take an actual MAC address. Be careful if you use virtual machines who generaly have fake network cards .

Comment: Not quite accurate, uuid1 has a higher probability of collision. uuid.uuid4() is guaranteed to never collide, since it's a random 128-bit integer. Being able to collide a 128-bit integer is equivalent to being able to hack a specific public Bitcoin address (Impossible, and would also net you [Billions of Dollars](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/address/34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo) if you could). uuid1 is feasible, if your clock is wrong and get unlucky or get UUIDs from two machines at the same time or you simply sample it too quickly.

Epoch gets used into the RNG that seeds uuid4.

Answer (score 6):

You should always have a duplicate check, even though the odds are pretty good, you can always have duplicates.

I would recommend just adding a duplicate key constraint in your database and in case of an error retry.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you create all uuids on same system, unless there is a very serious flaw in python implementation (what I really **cannot** imagine), RFC 4122 states that they will all be distinct (edited : if using version 1,3 or 5).

The only problem that could arise with UUID, were if two systems create UUID exactly at the same moment and :

- use same MAC address on their network card (really uncommon) and you are using UUID version 1
- or use same name and you are using UUID version 3 or 5
- or got same random number and you are using UUID version 4 (*)

So if you have a real MAC address or use an official DNS name or a unique LDAP DN, you can take for true that the generated uuids will be globally unique.

So IMHO, you only have to check unicity if you want to prevent your application against a malicious *attack* trying to voluntaryly use an existant uuid.

EDIT:
As stated by Martin Konecny, in uuid4 the timestamp part is random too and not monotonic. So the possibilily is collision is **very** limited but not 0.

Answer (score 0):

The universally correct way to generate a UUID on a personal computer is `uuid4`, you should never use any other way except if specifically desired (Specific Desires shown below).

---

uuid4 is also guaranteed to be unique from UUID's generated from other computers.

In addition, uuid4 is *currently* [cryptographically secure](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/434db68ee31514ddc4aa93f8dfc2eb874d3669c5/Lib/uuid.py#L723), meaning even if you expose your UUID's over the internet, the PRNG and entropy are strong enough to prevent others from guessing future UUID's you might generate. However, this is [not guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4), so if cryptographic security matters for your application and you're handling sensitive user information, use [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) instead.

- Note that when using V1's timestamp and MAC, if your UUID's are exposed over the internet, people can easily guess future timestamps and you've already exposed your MAC, creating collisions.

This guarantee is based on the 122-bits of randomness in a UUID, making it of [equivalent difficulty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118928/what-does-it-mean-that-the-security-of-bitcoin-public-keys-and-256-bit-ecdsa-is) to hacking a [Bitcoin wallet](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/address/34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo)

---

- **Version 1:** UUIDs using timestamp and MAC Address.

  - If you generate at the same timestamp, it will do +1
  - Specific Desire: When looking through business logs, it can tell you when it was generated and what machine generated it.
- **Version 2:** Not Used
- **Version 3:** UUIDs based on the MD5 hash of given data. (Same as SHA1)
- **Version 4:** UUIDs with [random data](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid)

  - Specific Desire: You want the strongest guarantee of uniqueness and security.
- **Version 5:** UUIDs based on the SHA1 hash of given data.

  - Specific Desire: When you want to be able to associate UUIDs with the "given data")

When you use V4, entropy is used to seed the PRNG. This includes timestamp, MAC address, and anything else collectible by the system (Internal RNG from CPU, Startup Time, Temperature readings, Disk Usage).

V1 is a kind of V4 where the only entropy is timestamp and MAC address and the PRNG is f(x) = x

Nuance into the discussion of urandom's security is [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key)