# How to extract time information from uuid in python

Tags: python, time, uuid

I'm trying to find an equivalent option of "uuid -d" linux command in python, and end up using below, as found in [Extract the time from a UUID v1 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795554/extract-the-time-from-a-uuid-v1-in-python) :

```
request_id = 78577992-6170-11e8-a1e4-f3a982af936e
request_uuid = uuid.UUID(request_id)
print (datetime.fromtimestamp((request_uuid.time - 0x01b21dd213814000L)*100/1e9))
```

which printed the time as "2018-05-27 15:40:31.803023", which is different from the actual time shows up in "uuid -d" command:

```
uuid -d 78577992-6170-11e8-a1e4-f3a982af936e |grep "content: time:"
    content: time:  2018-05-27 05:40:31.803022.6 UTC
```

Is there a correct option to extract time information from UUID in python, using uuid or any built-in modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided `request_id` is different from the uuid you test using `uuid -d`. If you correct this discrepancy they correspond (checked using answers to [Extract the time from a UUID v1 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795554/extract-the-time-from-a-uuid-v1-in-python)).

Comment: My bad.. corrected the question with actual UUID I'm dealing with.

Comment: And, that was it!!, partly because it was a wrong UUID I used to compare, and partly it was because "uuid -d" was printing the time in UTC, and UUID in python in local timezone. Once i wrapped up the extracted time with "datetime.utcfromtimestamp", it shows up correctly. Thanks for the pointers.